# Insert specific bounded numbers into a column in multi columns table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to update the `id` column in table and insert into `column1` to 600 like this:

Table before update:

```
id   name     date     comment
------------------------------
1    jack     9/10/12   null
100  david    9/11/12   20
158  sara     9/12/12   null
.
```

Table after update:

```
1    jack     9/10/12   null
2    david    9/11/12   20
3    sara     9/12/12   null
.
597   "     "      "
598   "     "      "
599   "     "      "
600   "     "      "
```

Comment: If the Id is the Primary Key, are they not referenced in other tables? Updating a PK is not advisable but if you do how would you want to keep other referenced tables updated?

Comment: do you need to change the ID for sequential ordering? don't do that. what if there are records on another table that are depending on that?

Comment: Sorry for that, SQL Server 2000 doesn't support CTE nor the Ranking function `ROW_NUMBER()`, thats why your are getting that error. I tagged your question with it waiting for someone to solve it.

Comment: id is not a primary key. tanx

Comment: Is `id` an identity column? These are not updatable.

Comment: no id isn't identity column.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to find out how many rows do you have

DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SET @COUNTER = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_tablename

Then declare a temparary table with almost the exact structure (except for the ID)

DECLARE @tmp_table TABLE
(
P_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
the rest of the field are the same
)

Now insert into the new table everything but the id

INSERT INTO @tmp_table
(SELECT name, date, comment FROM tbl_tablename)

Clear the original table

DELETE FROM tbl_tablename

and insert the values from the temparary table

INSERT INTO tbl_tablename (SELECT * FROM @tmp_table)

Now you can add the addional values

WHILE (@COUNTER <= 600)
    BEGIN
    SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
    INSERT INTO tbl_tablename (@COUNTER, '', null, null)
END

That's it. Hope it helps you